# A proper way to create complete backup?

Tags: backup

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction, just trying to make a complete backup of my phone (Samsung Galaxy S22), so I could back everything up when needed, I have tried the 'Titanium Backup' and 'Swift Backup' tools so far, but they only back up the .apks, and my Google login credentials are lost.

I am really kind of lost browsing through some 11-year-old topics about 'nandroid' and 'ClockWorkMod', do people use these tools today?

Comment: Is your phone rooted? Without root most data will remain inaccessible even for backup.

Comment: Yes, it is rooted

Answer (score 1):

For a non-rooted phone, I have found Samsung **Smart Switch** the best option.  But it will not restore to non-Samsung phones.  I may still work for rooted phones.

Otherwise, I quite like [MyPhoneExplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client&gl=US).  You can see what you are backing up in the filesystem and it has numerous options on what you want to back up.

However, I do not believe that you can backup/restore

- Paid-for apps - I guess it's a safety feature for developers.  Otherwise, you could get multiple copies of paid-for apps working.
- Credentials - Again, I believe it's a safety feature for you.

If you save passwords to your **Google Account** for Android App and Chrome, then I think these could be restored.

From [support.google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6197437)

> Use passwords across your devices
> You can sign in to apps and sites on different devices using passwords saved to your Google Account when you either:
>
> - Turn on sync in Chrome on Android
> - Sign in to Chrome on your computer